# Java SWT: remove selection of a tree item

Tags: java, tree, swt

I need to create a popup Menu for a Tree in Java SWT. But the menu should only pop up when no items are selected (when I click on a blank space of the TreeViewer). If I now select an item of the tree, I can't deselect it again. The TreeViewer is inside a Composite.
My first idea was to add a MouseListener to check if no of the Items are selected and call `deselectAll()`, but `event.getSource()` only returns the tree.
Any ideas of how to remove an item selection when a blank space is (right-) clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often, you can deselect by Ctlr-clicking the item.

Another option is to register a listener for mouse clicks, and use the event location to locate the tree item. If this returns null, you can call `deselectAll()`.

But how can you get the `TreeViewer` from the `Tree`? Simple: Store the reference in the `data` property of the tree. Then you can use this code in your event handler:

```
TreeViewer view = (TreeViewer) event.getSource().getData();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! But I can't add a usefull listener to the TreeViewer to check which item was clicked. What was your idea?

Comment: You need to add the listener to the `Tree`. A `TreeViewer` is just a helper class that makes it more simple to display a tree model in a tree; most of the work is still done with the underlying tree widget.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The MouseListener is already on the Tree. I need to find out if an item or a blank space is clicked (rightclick prefered). If I try to get the location with `((Tree) event.getSource()).getLocation()`, it always returns the same Point, no matter where I click.

Comment: You must call `tree.getItem(point)`. That returns an item or `null`

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. If I call `tree.getItem(((Tree) event.getSource()).getLocation())` inside the `mouseDown(MouseEvent event)` method of the tree MouseListener it always returns `null`.

Comment: So what? Why are you calling `getLocation()` anyway? It's not useful in this context.

Comment: I couldn't find any method for the event, which returns a location. That's why I tried to get the location of the tree, but as you said, it's not useful. Maybe I have an incorrect approach to this?

Comment: Event contains the location in `event.x` and `event.y`. You have to create a `Point` with `new Point(event.x, event.y)` and then, you can use `tree.getItem(point)`

Comment: That's the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

event.getSource().getLocation() just tells you the current location of the Tree widget in the parent coordinate system, that's why it's always the same. You need to get the click coordinates from the MouseEvent instead. It has x and y, which should be the click coordinates.

To sum up:

```
Tree tree = (Tree) event.getSource();
if (tree.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y)) != null)
    // an item was clicked.
else
    // no item was clicked.
```